# Jdbc Column index out of range

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Can anyone tell me why the getColumnClassName would tell me the column index was out of range when the rs.getString call on the line before works fine and I start iterating at 1?

```
int i = 1;
    while (rs.next()) {

        columns.put("id", Integer.toString(i));
        columns.put("name", rs.getString(4));
        columns.put("type", rs.getMetaData().getColumnClassName(i));
        columns.put("nullable", Integer.toString(rs.getMetaData().isNullable(i)));

        i++;
        s.add(columns);
    }
    return s;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `i` variable needs to be reset to `1` each time through the while loop. The current logic will be `getColumnClassName(2)` on the second record and `getColumnClassName(3)` on the 3rd record, etc. If you have more records than columns selected, you will get the index out of range error.

It is not clear if you are wanting to get the data from the record or just metadata about the columns returned.

If you are actually wanting to iterate over all the columns to get type information, you need to get the [column count](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnCount%28%29) and use that.

```
final int cnt = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

for (int i=0; i<cnt; ++i)
{
    columns.put("id", Integer.toString(i));
    columns.put("name", rs.getMetaData().getColumnName());
    columns.put("type", rs.getMetaData().getColumnClassName(i));
    columns.put("nullable", Integer.toString(rs.getMetaData().isNullable(i)));

    s.add(columns);
}
```